# Finding $\Delta p$ for discontinuous wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

So I have a triangle Wavefunction defined as:

$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}x &0<x<\frac{L}{2} \\ L-x &\frac{L}{2}<x<L\end{cases}$$

When I try to find the uncertainty in momentum, I find that it is zero.  This cannot be possible by Heisenberg.  So I am wondering if I have to (or how to) account for the discontinuity in the wavefunction when using the $\hat p$ operator.

Comment: Calculate in momentum space. The [Fourier transform of this  triangle signal](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/triangle.php) is derivable everywhere, so you would have no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to avoid the non-continuous derivative at L/2 by splitting the integral into two parts 1) from 0 to $L/2 - \epsilon$ and 2) from $L/2 + \epsilon$ to L.  Then take the limit as $\epsilon->0$ of your expectation value for p.  This will give you $<p>$, which is nonzero.  You'll also need $<p^2>$ (which you should find to be zero).  The uncertainty in momentum can then be calculated from $<p>$ and $<p^2>$.